# In this figure, prove that $PT^2 -PU^2 = QT^2$

Tags: geometry

Consider the following figure, with two concentric circles and tangents $PU$ and $PT$ from a point $P$ to both circles, with $PT$ the tangent to the smaller circle. Let $PT$ meet the larger circle at $Q$. Prove that

$$PT^2 - PU^2 = QT^2$$
[image]

By the tangent-secant theorem,

$$PU^2 = PG\times PA$$

$$PT^2 = PF\times PA$$

Also, $QT$ is a tangent to the smaller circle from $Q$, so, by the same theorem,

$$QT^2 = QE\times QA$$

So, we are required to prove,

$$PF\times PA - PG\times PA = QE\times QA$$

Or,

$$PA\times(PF - PG) = QE\times QA$$

$$=PA\times (FG) = QE\times QA$$

Since $FG = QE$,

$$PA = QA$$

which is clearly false. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You went wrong in that $PU^2\neq PG\cdot PA$. Rather the formula says $PU^2=PG\cdot (PA+AG)$. This means you dont "stop" at the center of the circle, but rather where the cord, here diameter, intersects the circle.